# How can I speed up insert/update 1-2mb text field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, insert, performance

I write bot that collect web pages but some pages is large around 1-2mb (normally large Ex. pantip.com) so how can i speed up now

it take 4-9 sec to update per row if meet over 1mb pages.

Thank in advance

Comment: Can you show us the queries you execute, and the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statements?

Answer (score 1):

You need to definitely increase max_allowed_packet and restart mysql. Something like

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=256M
```

One of the silent killers of MySQL is the MySQL Packet which is governed by [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet).

Understanding what the MySQL Packet is may clarify this.

According to the [page 99 of "Understanding MySQL Internals" (ISBN 0-596-00957-7)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009577), here are paragraphs 1-3 explaining it:

> MySQL network communication code was
>   written under the assumption that
>   queries are always reasonably short,
>   and therefore can be sent to and
>   processed by the server in one chunk,
>   which is called a *packet* in MySQL
>   terminology. The server allocates the
>   memory for a temporary buffer to store
>   the packet, and it requests enough to
>   fit it entirely. This architecture
>   requires a precaution to avoid having
>   the server run out of memory---a cap
>   on the size of the packet, which this
>   option accomplishes.
>
> The code of interest in relation to
>   this option is found in
>   **sql/net_serv.cc**. Take a look at **my_net_read()**, then follow the call to **my_real_read()** and pay
>   particular attention to
>   **net_realloc()**.
>
> This variable also limits the length
>   of a result of many string functons.
>   See **sql/field.cc** and
>   **sql/intem_strfunc.cc** for details.

Given this explanation, making bulk INSERTs will load/unload a MySQL Packet rather quickly. This is especially true when max_allowed_packet is too small for the given load of data coming at it.

**CONCLUSION**

In most installs of MySQL, I usually set this to 256M or 512M. You should experiment with larger values with data loads involving BLOB and TEXT fields.

Comment: i will try this i set only 32m

Answer (score 0):

use LOAD DATA instead of insert for bulk insert

Are you using individual statements for each record? You might want to look at the LOAD DATA infile for a bulk update.

Tips for fast insertion:

Use the LOAD DATA INFILE syntax to let MySQL parse it and insert it, even if you have to mangle it and feed it after the manipulation.
Use this insert syntax:

insert into table (col1, col2) values (val1, val2), (val3, val4), ...

Remove all keys/indexes prior to insertion.

Do it in the fastest machine you've got (IO-wise mainly, but RAM and CPU also matter). Both the DB server, but also the inserting client, remember you'll be paying twice the IO price (once reading, the second inserting)

[MySQL Inserting large data sets from file with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066264/mysql-inserting-large-data-sets-from-file-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

*We can help you better if you show us the queries, the table information (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`), information about the server, the MySQL settings and maybe some example data.*

But in general:

- Try using transactions: `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, lots of inserts, `COMMIT` will be faster then lots of inserts;
- You can do INSERTs in a cache, in temporary tables or in files, and only later load them into your permanent table.
- You should take care to setup your server correctly, using the correct size for your buffers, and the correct table storage engine.
- You can partition a table over multiple disks, to speed up inserts.
- You can disable triggers and indexes during the inserts.
- If you insert multiple rows at once, do one INSERT with multiple VALUES.