# What does rewritebatchedStatements do internally in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbc

Doing some benchmarking of code, and I was trying to improve the performance of batch writes. I'm currently using Spring's jdbcTemplate to insert batch with `updateBatch`.

I'm inserting 50000 records per batch. With `rewritebatchedStatements=true`, it takes roughly 60 seconds to insert all these records.

However, if I pre-sort the records via primary key, I can get this down to 2 seconds.

Sorting 50,000 records in my application layer is trivially fast, so what's the cause of slow inserts in MySQL when the data is not sorted?

Comment: It sounds like MySQL is trashing the indices - I'm not sure what effect, if any, `rewritebatchedStatements` has on the process (e.g. does it correlate at all to sorting/not-sorting first?)

Comment: Maybe it's simply combining N-inserts into one http://stackoverflow.com/a/2297647/2864740 .. how does *that* affect MySQL? I guess not much ..

Comment: Any way you can post some example code and schema which displays this behavior ?

Answer (score -1):

One reason may be mysql b+tree index, if inserted records have primary key, mysql will create index on primary key. Then if re-inserting records with primary keys lower then inserted keys, create B+tree index will expend more time.