# Insert 2 million records into table from file

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have 2 million records in file. and i'm trying to insert all records into my table. i'm very complicated with which way i should use. `LOAD DATA INFILE` or `hibernate begin transaction`. 
How to insert all data very fast?

File format is `txt` and its separated with line. need to insert only one row and others will generate auto.

sorry for bad English.

Comment: add table structure and file structure  also

Comment: @ChannaJayamuni added :)

Comment: where? its not present at the question?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066264/mysql-inserting-large-data-sets-from-file-with-java) answer

Answer (score 0):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` is first choice of mysql database users. But if you want to validate the data then you need efforts for that. You can also use `Data Integration` tools for that. For ex- [talend](https://www.talend.com/) is open source Data integration tool. By clicks it load from file to database and so on. Its useful for large data set. You can also validate and cleaning your data.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use `Load Data Infile` but here is another problem. when i finish process i get this warning :

WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Warning Code: 1062, SQLState: 23000
' for key 'PRIMARY'

its my query

```
String query = " LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE :file " +
                " IGNORE INTO TABLE Code" +
                " (code) " +
                " SET point = 0, created = NOW(), activated = 0; ";
```

and when i check my records from mysql there has no value on CODE column

```
+-----------+-------+------+-----------+---------------+---------------------+
| code      | point | user | activated | activatedDate | created             |
+-----------+-------+------+-----------+---------------+---------------------+
|     0 | NULL |         0 | NULL          | 2015-10-01 16:35:02 |
|     0 | NULL |         0 | NULL          | 2015-10-01 16:35:02 |
+-----------+-------+------+-----------+---------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```